# The page content is too wide

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to fix issues that page speed insights recommend me, anyway I don't understand one problem:

The page content is too wide for the viewport, forcing the user  to scroll
horizontally. Size the page content to the viewport to provide a better 
user experience.

The page content i 438 pixels wide but the viewport is only 375 css
pixels wide.

Here's website: http://goo.gl/PJRMO9

I can't find this problem on my website, I can't find that place where I need to scroll horizontally. Maybe someone could determine where is the problem, because I simply don't know where to fix this problem.

My problem is a bit different than provided in possible duplicate because problem was related to font size.

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's not wide for me at all.

Comment: But recommendations says something different, so there should be a problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30460380/page-speed-insights-size-content-to-viewport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is on the mobile version of your site. Please see scren below and explaination underneath.

[image: Mobile overflow problem]

I think this might cause this strange error. My recommendation is to decrease font size for this h1 element.

You can observe this using google chrome dev tools and Device mode (you can turn it on in chrome dev tools with ctrl+shift+m and reload page). Try to enter mobile mode in dev tools and change css on body from:
overflow-x: hidden!important;
to overflow-x: visible !important;

Reload page on mobile mode, and scroll down. You should see this:

[image: Overflow error :)]

Comment: Thank you so much! The answer is so clear. Decreasing font size fixed issue immediately.

Comment: No problem! I'm glad it helped. Greetings from Poland! :-)

Comment: Greetings from Lithuania too! We are not that far away. And Thanks again, I really appreciate it!